# Java: Multiplied values in Double Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, sqlite, android-sensors

I'm working on an Android app that will record sensors data into SQLite database.

The procedure looks as follows:

1. Add all values from the sensor to double arrays. One double array for each dimension, for example for accelerometer I have 3 double arrays (one for x values, one for y values and one for z values).
2. When all values are in the double arrays, convert double arrays to strings.
3. Put strings to relevant columns in SQLite table.

I faced an issue when I have multiplied values in every double array.

Here's the fragment of the code:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(final SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

    if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        //Getting and displaying accelerometer data
        x = sensorEvent.values[0];
        y = sensorEvent.values[1];
        z = sensorEvent.values[2];
    }

    if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
        //Getting and displaying gyroscope data
        x2 = sensorEvent.values[0];
        y2 = sensorEvent.values[1];
        z2 = sensorEvent.values[2];
    }

    if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {
        //Getting and displaying gyroscope data
        x3 = sensorEvent.values[0]; // x*sin(θ/2)
        y3 = sensorEvent.values[1]; // y*sin(θ/2)
        z3 = sensorEvent.values[2]; // z*sin(θ/2)
        cos3 = sensorEvent.values[3]; // cos(θ/2)
        accuracy3 = sensorEvent.values[4]; // estimated heading Accuracy (in radians) (-1 if unavailable)
    }

    //Start recording sensor data on click
    Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //Get label from EditText
            label = textLabel.getText().toString();

            statusText.setText("Wait");
            statusText.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            //Get current date and time
            currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            dateTime = currentTime.toString();

            flag = true; //flag set to true = record data
            samples = 0;
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    });


    //Insert given number of sensor data samples into database
    if (samples < samples_total) {
        if (flag == true) {

            //Get current date and time
            currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            dateTime = currentTime.toString();

            //Add x,y,z values to arrays for sensors
            accDoubleArrayX[samples] = x;
            accDoubleArrayY[samples] = y;
            accDoubleArrayZ[samples] = z;

            gyroDoubleArrayX[samples] = x2;
            gyroDoubleArrayY[samples] = y2;
            gyroDoubleArrayZ[samples] = z2;

            rotationDoubleArrayX[samples] = x3;
            rotationDoubleArrayY[samples] = y3;
            rotationDoubleArrayZ[samples] = z3;
            rotationDoubleArrayCos[samples] = cos3;
            rotationDoubleArrayAccuracy[samples] = accuracy3;

            samples++;

        } else {
            //Log.d("", "samples < total but Flag is false - Data NOT inserted");
        }
    } else if (samples == samples_total) {
        durationTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

        //Insert x,y,z values for sensors
        dbRef.insertData(dateTime, accDoubleArrayX, accDoubleArrayY, accDoubleArrayZ,
                gyroDoubleArrayX, gyroDoubleArrayY, gyroDoubleArrayZ,
                rotationDoubleArrayX, rotationDoubleArrayY, rotationDoubleArrayZ, rotationDoubleArrayCos, rotationDoubleArrayAccuracy,
                durationTime, label);

        Log.d("", "Data inserted!");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Data inserted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //Stop recording when given number of samples inserted
        flag = false;
        samples++;

    } else {
        //Not in use
    }

}
```

And also insertData method:

```
//Inserting data
public boolean insertData(String start_time,
                          double[] acc_x, double[] acc_y, double[] acc_z,
                          double[] gyro_x, double[] gyro_y, double[] gyro_z,
                          double[] rotation_x, double[] rotation_y, double[] rotation_z, double[] rotation_cos, double[] rotation_accuracy,
                          long duration_time, String label) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_REC_TIME, start_time);
    contentValues.put(COL_ACC_X, Arrays.toString(acc_x));
    contentValues.put(COL_ACC_Y, Arrays.toString(acc_y));
    contentValues.put(COL_ACC_Z, Arrays.toString(acc_z));
    contentValues.put(COL_GYRO_X, Arrays.toString(gyro_x));
    contentValues.put(COL_GYRO_Y, Arrays.toString(gyro_y));
    contentValues.put(COL_GYRO_Z, Arrays.toString(gyro_z));
    contentValues.put(COL_ROTATION_X, Arrays.toString(rotation_x));
    contentValues.put(COL_ROTATION_Y, Arrays.toString(rotation_y));
    contentValues.put(COL_ROTATION_Z, Arrays.toString(rotation_z));
    contentValues.put(COL_ROTATION_COS, Arrays.toString(rotation_cos));
    contentValues.put(COL_ROTATION_ACCURACY, Arrays.toString(rotation_accuracy));
    contentValues.put(COL_DURATION, String.valueOf(duration_time));
    contentValues.put(COL_LABEL, label);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

This code works almost as expected but gives me multiplied values. The values in arrays looks for example like this:

```
accDoubleArrayX: [2.013523578643799, 2.013523578643799, 2.013523578643799, 2.492363929748535, 2.492363929748535, 2.492363929748535, -7.771578788757324, -7.771578788757324, -7.771578788757324, 2.0913352966308594, 2.0913352966308594, 2.0913352966308594, 9.205705642700195, 9.205705642700195, 9.205705642700195, -2.649184226989746, -2.649184226989746, -2.649184226989746, 0.851138710975647, 0.851138710975647, 0.851138710975647, 1.4508862495422363, 1.4508862495422363, 1.4508862495422363, 3.1938650608062744, 3.1938650608062744, 3.1938650608062744, 1.7621324062347412, 1.7621324062347412, 1.7621324062347412, -5.260061264038086, -5.260061264038086]   
accDoubleArrayY: [5.456385612487793, 5.456385612487793, 5.456385612487793, 7.893682956695557, 7.893682956695557, 7.893682956695557, 3.6786909103393555, 3.6786909103393555, 3.6786909103393555, 2.8095955848693848, 2.8095955848693848, 2.8095955848693848, 6.449979305267334, 6.449979305267334, 6.449979305267334, 5.60602331161499, 5.60602331161499, 5.60602331161499, 5.076904773712158, 5.076904773712158, 5.076904773712158, -0.05985504388809204, -0.05985504388809204, -0.05985504388809204, 2.78086519241333, 2.78086519241333, 2.78086519241333, 6.861782073974609, 6.861782073974609, 6.861782073974609, 4.49870491027832, 4.49870491027832]    
accDoubleArrayZ: [18.986019134521484, 18.986019134521484, 18.986019134521484, 0.5770025849342346, 0.5770025849342346, 0.5770025849342346, 6.994660377502441, 6.994660377502441, 6.994660377502441, 13.217190742492676, 13.217190742492676, 13.217190742492676, 2.6240451335906982, 2.6240451335906982, 2.6240451335906982, -9.330204010009766, -9.330204010009766, -9.330204010009766, 9.876082420349121, 9.876082420349121, 9.876082420349121, 13.722367286682129, 13.722367286682129, 13.722367286682129, 4.235342979431152, 4.235342979431152, 4.235342979431152, -10.040084838867188, -10.040084838867188, -10.040084838867188, -1.8638859987258911, -1.8638859987258911]   

gyroDoubleArrayX: [-0.575242817401886, 0.14913702011108398, 0.14913702011108398, 0.14913702011108398, 2.141181468963623, 2.141181468963623, 2.141181468963623, -4.218447208404541, -4.218447208404541, -4.218447208404541, -0.030892670154571533, -0.030892670154571533, -0.030892670154571533, 5.554288864135742, 5.554288864135742, 5.554288864135742, -2.211488962173462, -2.211488962173462, -2.211488962173462, -5.499960422515869, -5.499960422515869, -5.499960422515869, -1.3646037578582764, -1.3646037578582764, -1.3646037578582764, 7.179882526397705, 7.179882526397705, 7.179882526397705, 1.353951096534729, 1.353951096534729, 1.353951096534729, -5.861084938049316]   
gyroDoubleArrayY: [-0.4165183901786804, -1.6266587972640991, -1.6266587972640991, -1.6266587972640991, -1.0279802083969116, -1.0279802083969116, -1.0279802083969116, 3.4663705825805664, 3.4663705825805664, 3.4663705825805664, -7.069095134735107, -7.069095134735107, -7.069095134735107, 0.3334277868270874, 0.3334277868270874, 0.3334277868270874, 2.221076488494873, 2.221076488494873, 2.221076488494873, -0.21944448351860046, -0.21944448351860046, -0.21944448351860046, -3.3257555961608887, -3.3257555961608887, -3.3257555961608887, 0.04580637067556381, 0.04580637067556381, 0.04580637067556381, 0.3419498801231384, 0.3419498801231384, 0.3419498801231384, 1.2857742309570312]  
gyroDoubleArrayZ: [0.0649811327457428, -0.18002969026565552, -0.18002969026565552, -0.18002969026565552, 0.2865561246871948, 0.2865561246871948, 0.2865561246871948, -0.7233145833015442, -0.7233145833015442, -0.7233145833015442, -0.6796387434005737, -0.6796387434005737, -0.6796387434005737, -1.1739214658737183, -1.1739214658737183, -1.1739214658737183, -3.5452001094818115, -3.5452001094818115, -3.5452001094818115, -0.014913702383637428, -0.014913702383637428, -0.014913702383637428, -0.6348975896835327, -0.6348975896835327, -0.6348975896835327, -0.9310411214828491, -0.9310411214828491, -0.9310411214828491, -2.379800796508789, -2.379800796508789, -2.379800796508789, -0.6317018270492554]    

rotationDoubleArrayX: [0.2823379933834076, 0.2823379933834076, 0.26849400997161865, 0.26849400997161865, 0.26849400997161865, 0.2820430099964142, 0.2820430099964142, 0.2820430099964142, 0.35002198815345764, 0.35002198815345764, 0.35002198815345764, 0.20867300033569336, 0.20867300033569336, 0.20867300033569336, 0.2366899996995926, 0.2366899996995926, 0.2366899996995926, 0.39944401383399963, 0.39944401383399963, 0.39944401383399963, 0.3354569971561432, 0.3354569971561432, 0.3354569971561432, 0.17095300555229187, 0.17095300555229187, 0.17095300555229187, 0.1272200047969818, 0.1272200047969818, 0.1272200047969818, 0.34220200777053833, 0.34220200777053833, 0.34220200777053833]    
rotationDoubleArrayY: [0.10564299672842026, 0.10564299672842026, 0.08853700011968613, 0.08853700011968613, 0.08853700011968613, 0.04211900010704994, 0.04211900010704994, 0.04211900010704994, 0.01869099959731102, 0.01869099959731102, 0.01869099959731102, 0.1025020033121109, 0.1025020033121109, 0.1025020033121109, -0.10204900056123734, -0.10204900056123734, -0.10204900056123734, -0.06824100017547607, -0.06824100017547607, -0.06824100017547607, 0.03044299967586994, 0.03044299967586994, 0.03044299967586994, 0.026799000799655914, 0.026799000799655914, 0.026799000799655914, -0.07169300317764282, -0.07169300317764282, -0.07169300317764282, -0.07498300075531006, -0.07498300075531006, -0.07498300075531006]  
rotationDoubleArrayZ: [0.19162000715732574, 0.19162000715732574, 0.18857499957084656, 0.18857499957084656, 0.18857499957084656, 0.16563500463962555, 0.16563500463962555, 0.16563500463962555, 0.15753500163555145, 0.15753500163555145, 0.15753500163555145, 0.16617600619792938, 0.16617600619792938, 0.16617600619792938, 0.0989999994635582, 0.0989999994635582, 0.0989999994635582, 0.0755779966711998, 0.0755779966711998, 0.0755779966711998, -0.011357000097632408, -0.011357000097632408, -0.011357000097632408, -0.0029909999575465918, -0.0029909999575465918, -0.0029909999575465918, -0.039792999625205994, -0.039792999625205994, -0.039792999625205994, -0.05465399846434593, -0.05465399846434593, -0.05465399846434593]    
rotationDoubleArrayCos: [0.9340260028839111, 0.9340260028839111, 0.9404839873313904, 0.9404839873313904, 0.9404839873313904, 0.94405597448349, 0.94405597448349, 0.94405597448349, 0.9232100248336792, 0.9232100248336792, 0.9232100248336792, 0.9582970142364502, 0.9582970142364502, 0.9582970142364502, 0.9611250162124634, 0.9611250162124634, 0.9611250162124634, 0.911083996295929, 0.911083996295929, 0.911083996295929, 0.9414939880371094, 0.9414939880371094, 0.9414939880371094, 0.9849100112915039, 0.9849100112915039, 0.9849100112915039, 0.9884790182113647, 0.9884790182113647, 0.9884790182113647, 0.9350330233573914, 0.9350330233573914, 0.9350330233573914] 
rotationDoubleArrayAccuracy: [246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0, 246.0]
```

As you can see first 3 values for accelerometer are the same, next 3 are the same, and so on. 
For gyroscope: first value is unique, then three are the same, next 3 are the same, and so on. 
For rotation vector: first two are the same, then next three are the same, then next 3, and so on.

For me it seems really strange and I can't find the solution for this issue.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because everytime when sensor event is received, you populate arrays for ALL 3 event types instead of populating arrays for only one event type (the type for which the event has been received).

In order to avoid that, you need to keep three separate counters for each event type.

Also, As far as I understood, you want to insert your sample arrays into DB when all of them have been completely filled. Hence you also need to modify your condition for DB insertion.

Hence the populating routine should be modified like this:

```
if (samples_acc < samples_total || samples_gyro < samples_total || samples_rotation < samples_total) 
                {
                            if (flag == true) 
                            {

                                //Get current date and time
                                currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                                dateTime = currentTime.toString();

                                //Add x,y,z values to arrays for sensors

                                if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER && samples_acc < samples_total) 
                                {
                                accDoubleArrayX[samples_acc] = x;
                                accDoubleArrayY[samples_acc] = y;
                                accDoubleArrayZ[samples_acc] = z;

                                samples_acc++;
                                }

                                if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE && samples_gyro < samples_total) 
                                {
                                gyroDoubleArrayX[samples_gyro] = x2;
                                gyroDoubleArrayY[samples_gyro] = y2;
                                gyroDoubleArrayZ[samples_gyro] = z2;

                                samples_gyro++;
                                }

                                if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR && samples_rotation < samples_total) 
                                {
                                rotationDoubleArrayX[samples_rotation] = x3;
                                rotationDoubleArrayY[samples_rotation] = y3;
                                rotationDoubleArrayZ[samples_rotation] = z3;
                                rotationDoubleArrayCos[samples_rotation] = cos3;
                                rotationDoubleArrayAccuracy[samples_rotation] = accuracy3;

                                samples_rotation++;
                                }

                            }//end if flag=true
                            else 
                            {
                            //Log.d("", "samples < total but Flag is false - Data NOT inserted");
                            }
            }//end if at least one of arrays is not filled yet

            //all arrays have been filled   
            else 
            {
                durationTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

                //Insert x,y,z values for sensors
                dbRef.insertData(dateTime, accDoubleArrayX, accDoubleArrayY, accDoubleArrayZ,
                        gyroDoubleArrayX, gyroDoubleArrayY, gyroDoubleArrayZ,
                        rotationDoubleArrayX, rotationDoubleArrayY, rotationDoubleArrayZ, rotationDoubleArrayCos, rotationDoubleArrayAccuracy,
                        durationTime, label);

                Log.d("", "Data inserted!");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Data inserted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //Stop recording when given number of samples inserted
                flag = false;
            }
```

Oh, and one additional note about your button: you better move it out of your `onSensorChanged` method because it doesn't make sense to redeclare it everytime when a new event is received

Comment: This code works after adding the condition before inserting that all sensors samples must be equal to the total number of samples. And after setting flag to false increment +1 to all sensors samples is required to not fall into the loop of inserting. But big thanks, thanks to your answer I can go forward with my programming :)